# Alamofire HTTPS request not working for this website

Tags: ios, swift, https, alamofire

I am new to ios/swift devel.
I am using Alamofire to get data with following piece of code:

```
let user = "abc"
let password = "def"

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://wis.fit.vutbr.cz/FIT/st/get-courses.php")
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

`NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “wis.fit.vutbr.cz” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “wis.fit.vutbr.cz” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7974ccd0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x797faf00>, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x797f7580 [0x94f098]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x797f8930) s: wis.fit.vutbr.cz i: Brno University of Technology CA>
    1 : <cert(0x797fa2a0) s: Brno University of Technology CA i: Brno University of Technology CA>
)}}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://wis.fit.vutbr.cz/FIT/st/get-courses.php, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x797f7580 [0x94f098]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x797f8930) s: wis.fit.vutbr.cz i: Brno University of Technology CA>
    1 : <cert(0x797fa2a0) s: Brno University of Technology CA i: Brno University of Technology CA>
)}, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x797faf00>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://wis.fit.vutbr.cz/FIT/st/get-courses.php}`

I've also turned off ATS in Info.plist since it seems to be a common problem on iOS 9.0.

I get this error even when I try to retrieve data from https://www.fit.vutbr.cz
Any help? I am completely lost in this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not connected to the NSAppTransportSecurity,

Looks like this website has either self-signed or shared certificate,
iOS does rejects request because it can not verify the certificate, 
If you are admin of the website then - use proper certificate,
If there is "http" version of this site , you could use that,
otherwise you have to accept this certificate, which is not available via Alamofire at the moment, you can have a look at this topic - [How to implement self signed certificates in Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868126/how-to-implement-self-signed-certificates-in-alamofire)

Comment: how do i find out whether the website has self-signed or shared certificate?

Comment: try opening the website with a browser ( for example google chrome ) , then on the left side of the URL text field , you can see red-https and lock sign , click on it to see the details

Comment: thanks for help. however, the problem was that the certificate alamofire was supposed to use was in the project directory, but it wasn't included in the bundle. therefore alamofire couldn't find it